# How to map my views into controller via routes?

Tags: laravel, routes

In my `PersonController` i add an extra function that aims to produce a report from my `Person` model, this is how i created it:

```
public function generatePersonDetails(Person $person){
    dd($person);
}
```

on my `web` routes i have this definition:

```
Route::resource('/person', 'PersonController'); 
Route::get('/person/person-details-report/{{ person }}', 'PersonController@generatePersonDetails');
```

and on my page, i have this:

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('/person/person-details-report/'.$person) }}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-small" id="lt-btn-cancel" style="border-radius: 0;"></i>Person Details</a>
```

but if i click my anchor tag that is the **Person Details**, i got a `404|Not Found`, however on my address bar i got `http://127.0.0.1:8000/person/person-details-report/%7B%22id%22:1,%22person_id%22:1,%22receiver%22:%22Family%20Name,%20First%20Name%22,%22created_at%22:%222019-08-25%2011:27:08%22,%22updated_at%22:%222019-09-01%2012:00:20%22%7D`.

What should i do with my routes?

Comment: I think you are passing a whole person object in the URL instead of person id. just pass person id in the URL and get details of the person in the action to generate a report.

Comment: i just got the same result if i pass an id only.

Comment: pls replace public function generatePersonDetails(Person $person) TO public function generatePersonDetails($person).

Comment: Relace with it : <a href="{{ URL('/person/person-details-report/'.$person->id )}}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-small" id="lt-btn-cancel" style="border-radius: 0;"></i>Person Details</a>

Answer (score 0):

You need to swap and edit your routes and order. Additional routes fro resource controller needs to be first, because the possible conflict.

```
Route::get('/person/person-details-report/{person}', 'PersonController@generatePersonDetails');
Route::resource('/person', 'PersonController');
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have some typos.

1. First change route definition to:

```php
Route::get('/person/person-details-report/{person}', 'PersonController@generatePersonDetails');
```

It should be `{person}` not `{{ person }}`

2. Second change the link url to

```php
<a href="{{ URL::to('/person/person-details-report', $person) }}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-small" id="lt-btn-cancel" style="border-radius: 0;"></i>Person Details</a>
```

You should pass `$person` as a second argument or you could directly pass the person's id like this:

```php
<a href="{{ URL::to('/person/person-details-report/' . $person->id) }}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-small" id="lt-btn-cancel" style="border-radius: 0;"></i>Person Details</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to change the route because you are using `{{person}}` instead of `{person}`:

```php
Route::get('/person/person-details-report/{person}', , 'PersonController@generatePersonDetails');
```

Second you have to change the URL generation to use the `$person->id`:

```php
<a href="{{ URL::to('/person/person-details-report/'.$person->id) }}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-small" id="lt-btn-cancel" style="border-radius: 0;"></i>Person Details</a>
```

Comment: I tried it but i get the same result. It leads me always to ```404 | Not Found```